# Usernames in Active Directory

Tags: azure-active-directory, active-directory, user-accounts

I’m in the process of integrating customer’s HR application(source system) with their Active Directory. Customer’s users require access to both on-premise and cloud applications. so they have both Azure AD and On-premise AD. In order to effectively manage joiners, movers and leavers identities , Customer need employee data from their system.

Customer is looking for HR system to define the username for any new users and expect that username to be communicated to their Active Director administrators which they will update as User logon name(pre-windows 200) when user account is being created

For e.g. HR administrators create a new employee John Doe in HR application. HR admin need define a username for John Doe i.e. jdoe which will be sent to AD adminstrators which will be updated user logon name in AD.

In this case, since HR administrators are responsible for defining username for new users, they will need to ensure a process in place on their HR applications to validate usernames are unique and ensure usernames are not duplicated.

I’m trying to understand what have been the common practices followed in AD for defining usernames.

Firs of all, is it a good practice to expect source system(single source of truth for HR data) to define usernames for new users? or Is it better AD team to own the process of defining user naming conventions?

May I request for any help in understanding best practices around this process please?

Thank you

I have looked into previous posts to see if there are any recommendations on this process but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

This question may be considered overly broad for Stack Overflow, but I'll give you my experience.

> is it a good practice to expect source system(single source of truth for HR data) to define usernames for new users? or Is it better AD team to own the process of defining user naming conventions?

If you are looking to formalize the process of creating usernames for new users, your HR system can be a good source for this. However, you will need to have conventions in place to deal with problems like these:

- Ensuring uniqueness among usernames, and how to handle duplicates. For example, you could append a number to the username if a duplicate is found.
- Removing illegal characters. Your user's first/last name could contain characters that would be considered invalid when using them to generate an AD username. A good example of this is accent marks that may appear over certain letters. Or maybe your organization prefers not to have usernames with spaces or apostrophes, even if AD accepts them.
- Ensuring the generated username is socially acceptable. This is more a problem with automated processes. For example, if the process generates a curse word, how will you detect/handle that?
- Ensuring the username is at most 20 characters, which is generally the AD limit. And what to do if it goes over that.

If you choose to automate the process (which people do), for example through a custom job that runs nightly and creates AD accounts for new hires, your process will need to read the HR database, determine who is new and whether they already have an AD account, and use AD APIs to create the account if necessary. Maybe the process would then email another group in IT to review the new account and complete the setup.

Whether it is an automated process or a human in HR that is generating the username, they will need to have access to AD and its rules in order to check some of the items above. That access can be direct or it can be through an IT POC who has access to AD.